# Unable to access active mq service from my tests in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, masstransit

First of all, **is there any restriction in GitLab free edition regarding services or docker containers?** It says I've got GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.11.0-rc1-ee

I have the following:

- A free account of gitlab for my personal repos
- A project that wraps MassTransit and uses ActiveMq as the transport layer
- a GitLab `.gitlab-ci.yml` that restores, build code and runs unit and integration tests and spins up a service `webcenter/activemq:5.14.3` to execute the integration tests.

My integration tests cannot connect to the spinned up container of active mq. It does not matter if I try the hostname "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" or "0.0.0.0"
I keep seeing a `ActiveMQ Connect Failed: NMSConnectionException`

If I run locally my tests with a local activemq server running (I simply downloaded the binaries, set the JAVA_HOME variable and ran bin/activemq start) everything works perfectly.

The funny thing is that I ran the same tests and the same code on a different pipeline in the GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.10.4-ee and everything goes way faster and my tests are executed properly pointing to "localhost" server name and also using `webcenter/activemq:5.14.3` service.

**UPDATE 1**: This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
#Stages
stages:
  - ci
  - pack

#Global variables
variables:
  GITLAB_RUNNER_DOTNET_CORE: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
  NUGET_REPOSITORY: $NEXUS_NUGET_REPOSITORY
  NUGET_API_KEY: $NEXUS_API_KEY
  NUGET_FOLDER_NAME: nupkgs

#Docker image
image: $GITLAB_RUNNER_DOTNET_CORE

#Jobs
ci:
  stage: ci
  services:
    - webcenter/activemq:5.14.3
  script:
    - dotnet restore --no-cache --force
    - dotnet build --configuration Release
    - dotnet vstest *Tests/bin/Release/**/*Tests.dll

pack-beta-nuget:
  stage: pack
  script:
    - export VERSION_SUFFIX=beta$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - dotnet pack *.sln --configuration Release --output $NUGET_FOLDER_NAME --version-suffix $VERSION_SUFFIX --include-source --include-symbols -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg
    - dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg --api-key $NUGET_API_KEY --source $NUGET_REPOSITORY
  except:
    - master

pack-nuget:
  stage: pack
  script:
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet pack *.sln --configuration Release --output $NUGET_FOLDER_NAME
    - dotnet nuget push **/*.nupkg --api-key $NUGET_API_KEY --source $NUGET_REPOSITORY
  only:
    - master
```

**UPDATE 2**: I use the following settings with MassTransit.ActiveMQ 5.3.2

```
HostName = "localhost"; //I have tried 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 also. Same result
Username = "admin";
Password = "admin";
Port = 61616;
UseSsl = false;
AutoDelete = true;
```

**UPDATE 3**: If I set the alias `activemq` to the service and then use the `HostName = "activemq"` it does not connect either.
If I don't set any alias but use the autogenerated `webcenter__activemq` I've got the same problem, it cannot connect.

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
ActiveMQ Connect Failed: NMSConnectionException
ActiveMQ Connect Failed: NMSConnectionException
ActiveMQ Connect Failed: NMSConnectionException
```

*UPDATE 4:* I made public my repository. It is a masstransit wrapper. All the unit/integration tests can be executed by simply having an instance of activemq running on 127.0.0.1.
Otherwise (especially for the CI pipeline) the file `DiDrDe.MessageBus.Infra.MassTransit.IntegrationTests\TestSupport\ActiveMqTestsConstants.cs` must be edited and the HostName must be changed to whichever value the CI's activeMq container is spinned up.

So far I've tried with `webcenter__activemq`, `127.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.0`, `localhost`, `activemq` (and set the same alias to the service) **but no luck**

Comment: You need to use the service alias and then use the same as the host name. Using the `localhost` will never work.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 works in another Gitlab's account pipeline, but not in my Gitlab's account.

Do you know which is the variable for that docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/webcenter/activemq/dockerfile that I can set, so that my hostname can point to it?

If I run the container locally and I set my MassTransit hostName to "192.168.99.1" it works because that's my virtualbox adapter IP (I use docker toolbox in Windows). Sorry for so many questions but I am a bit confused here and I suspect Gitlab has something to do with the way the same image is treated in some accounts

Comment: I will put an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use services in the CI pipeline all the time but we never used the loopback address. You mentioned that it worked, but it might have been the shell runner and now you probably are using the Docker runner.

GitLab documentation gives [clear guidelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services) on how to connect to services:

> Let’s say that you need a Wordpress instance to test some API
>   integration with your application.
>
> You can then use for example the `tutum/wordpress` image in your
>   `.gitlab-ci.yml`:
>
> ```
> services:
> - tutum/wordpress:latest
> ```
>
> If you don’t specify a service alias, when the job is run,
>   `tutum/wordpress` will be started and you will have access to it from
>   your build container under two hostnames to choose from:
>
> ```
> tutum-wordpress
> tutum__wordpress
> ```

You can also use service aliases that I mentioned in my first comment, as *also* [described](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#available-settings-for-services) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with the result. Unfortunately there must be something else involved because I'm still unable to connect to the activemq in the pipeline by referencing its alias

Comment: @diegosasw - Did you try to connect without the alias, using the auto-generated hostnames?

Comment: @beechovsky I haven't tried any auto-generated hostname, but I use aliases and it works fine for the docker runner.